# How to animate views in Activity when adding/removing a Fragment?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I need to add a Fragment to my Activity in code with a FragmentTransaction. 
In the process of adding the fragment, I need to animate some views in the original activity as well as views in the fragment. Also I need to reverse these animations when the fragment is removed.

1. setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit) can only set the animation for fragment.
2. If I start the animations in Fragment's life cycle methods like onDestroyView, will they finish before the views are destroyed?

Comment: You can post a message to your activity in Fragment's `onViewCreated` and `onViewDestroyed`, and on receiving the message you can load your animations

Comment: If you implemented a listener for your activity and fragment, then message posting may not be needed. Call the listener interface function, such as `onAddAnim , onReloadAnim, etc`